# My parents claimed me as a dependent, but I put on my tax form that no one can claim me as a dependent. Am I getting a stimulus check?

Tags: check, stimulus

the question pretty much says it all. My dad says he filed me a dependent because the only criteria was to have gone to college for one semester. Which I had done in 2019. I graduated May and moved to one of the most expensive cities in the country. I pay my own rent and I put on my tax form when I started my job that no one could claim me as a dependent. Am I getting a check? Any work around for this?

Comment: Note this means that your dad 'cheated' taxes - he got a deduction that he shouldn't have got. The IRS might not find out (because they are too busy with other stuff).

Comment: As Aganju said, your father is wrong. The requirement to claim someone is to pay at least 50% of their yearly living expenses, which he most certainly did not. Most likely the IRS will follow up with both of you in 1-2 years to get it sorted out. You might recommend that your dad file an amended return to prevent any fees/interest on the credit he should not have claimed.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to predict for sure what the IRS will use, but chances are very high that you will get a check, as you filed taxes for last year, and have a SSN. The IRS will probably not have the time to cross-reference all its other data, and follow up on disagreements.

Either way, you will get your part of it *for sure* when you file your taxes for 2020 (a year from now), as the 'check' in the next weeks is only a downpayment on a tax credit for 2020. The final amount and payment is decided when you file your taxes for 2020, and if you got too little or nothing, you will get it then (interestingly enough, the law says that if you got too much, you don't have to pay it back).